# How can I increment the counter in my css code?

Tags: html, css, list, css-tables, css-counter

In my `html` code I have the following list defined:

```
<p class="list">first.</p>
<p class="list">second.</p>
```

Now, in `css` I have:

```
.list {
  display: table;
}
.list:before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: counter;
  content: counter(counter) '.';
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

and the result on the page is:

```
1. first
1. second
```

How can I increment the second number to the value of 2?

Comment: I don't see why you just use an ordered list `<ol></ol>`. This is exactly what it is made for.

Comment: You are increasing an undeclared counter. But CSS is more sane than JS and this the counter becomes local, not global.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using `counter-reset` property on the *wrapper* of the `list`s - see demo below:

```css
body {
 counter-reset:counter;
}
.list {
  display: table;
}
.list:before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: counter;
  content: counter(counter) '.';
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="list">first.</p>
<p class="list">second.</p>
```

Comment: This answer best explains your question, though i would definitely consider using ordered lists instead, if this is your usage @user3766930

Comment: This works only, if there are no sublists.

Comment: OP not talking about sub-lists @ssc-hrep3?

Comment: @kukkuz:: Is this css property(counter-increment) has browser compatibility ? This is a right choice for using order listed items <ol></ol>.

Comment: guys, OP is about why `counter` did not work and not which is better or compatible :D

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wrapping your HTML in `<p>` tags, you could use:

```
<ol>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ol>
```

This will give you the output desired.

Here is a working [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nb1shs7v/)

This way you don't need to do any count stuff in CSS, much easier, simpler solution and compatible cross browser.

Comment: My guess, because it didn't answer the question `how to increase the counter using css` Good alternative though if OP would want to use different markup.

Comment: I have merely provided an alternative solution @NickSalloum and no where on SO does it say you cannot do this. I don't think there is any need for such comments from yourself. If my solution doesn't work there are other answers that the OP can use. How about you provide an answer instead of criticise others.

Comment: I agree more with this answer. OP is using weird CSS to get the styling/effect of a list... So use a list. Sometimes a good answer is not what OP litterly asked for.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset the counter:

```css
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}
.list {
  display: table;
}
.list:before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: section;
  content:counter(section) ". ";
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="list">first.</p>
<p class="list">second.</p>
```

Comment: are those `//` supposed to represent a comment? or is there something in css I don't know about? *lol*

Comment: Yes, they are supposed to be comments, and I removed them now, sorry about that

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah, those `//` are valid in C and PHP. `/* ... */` are comments in css ;-) but pretty sure you knew that ;-)

Comment: Yeah I realized that and removed them as soon as you pointed out. Happens when you are answering questions in more then one languages at the same time. Thanks for that

Comment: Hehe, I know what you mean. Good thing you fixed it, someone might have come and downvoted you (without commenting). *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials:</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials:</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>
```

*Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp*

Answer (score -2):

you should use like this:

```
<ol>
    <li class="list">first.</li>
    <li class="list">second.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why `should`? - We don't know why OP has the markup the way it is and wanting to use `<p>` tags and number them is not invalid HTML nor incorrect.

Comment: Original poster specifically asked about using counters, not ordered lists. While your reasoning might be validated, your answer is not helpful at all.